# MySQL subquery returns multiple rows, I want to compare a value to all rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to select a single (random) records from a table where one of its values is between 1 & 9, and it and the user ID present at the time are not present in a separate table (i.e. they haven't been used together before):

```
SELECT QuestionID 
FROM Questions 
WHERE ((Marks BETWEEN 1 AND 9) 
    AND QuestionID !=(
        SELECT QuestionID 
        FROM Username.History 
        WHERE UserID = 1
    )
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

But when I run this I get a subquery returns multiple rows error, is there a way to have it compare QuestionID to all QuestionID's from History?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT QuestionID 
FROM Questions 
WHERE ((Marks BETWEEN 1 AND 9) 
    AND QuestionID NOT IN (
        SELECT QuestionID 
        FROM Username.History 
        WHERE UserID = 1
    )
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Simply replace `!=` with `NOT IN`.

Comment: Great, thanks for that :) I'm a tad inexperienced so I wasn't aware that command existed